# When is $ 2^n-1=0\bmod (n^2-1) $?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, divisibility

I have tried to solve this equation $ 2^n-1=0\bmod (n^2-1) $ , I got using [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table+%282%5En-1+mod+%28n%C2%B2-1%29%29%2C+n%3D1+to+40) $n=2,4,16,36$ seems the solution are $0 \bmod 4$ however 8 is not a solution, probably  there are only finitely many solutions. Now, how do I get other solutions if it has finitely many solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence of numbers that solve your equation is [OEIS A247219](https://oeis.org/A247219). A note there says

> [This sequence contains] all numbers of the form $2^{2^k}$, $k\ge0$…

So there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Thanks, what I conjuctred is true , I conjuctred that the solution of the form 4^k such that k=0 mod 4

Comment: @Rafikmathz $36$ is not of the form $4^k$...

Comment: you are right , and my question here why this sequence since it has a closed form solution

Comment: @Rafikmathz That second question is unclear. I have already answered the question and you should accept it.

Comment: I meant why that sqeuence since the solution were proved that is of the form 2^2^k ?

Comment: @Rafikmathz Because there are numbers not in the sequence.